# Custom keras.applications model in keras

Tags: python, keras

I want to use `keras.applications.resnet50` to training a model.

But in my data, they are not only image, there are some variable term in table.

I see the document of keras, `keras.layers.concatenate` can combine two layer together after I flatten image term.

But `keras.applications.resnet50` can't concatenate variable term.

How to costumized layer base on pre-train model?

There is my demo code blow:

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential, concatenate
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.models import Model
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
VariableSize = 16
ResNet = ResNet50(include_top=True, weights=None, input_tensor=None, input_shape=(64,64,3), pooling=None, classes=2)
ResNet.layers.pop()
VariableNet = Input(shape=(VariableSize,))
ModelNet = keras.layers.concatenate([ResNet, VariableNet])  ##  Error
##
##  And connect output layer before complie
```

Comment: If your samples are simple vectors, instead of images, you shouldn't be using resnet

Comment: You should include any error messages (and tracebacks) that you get in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass `ResNet` as input to `keras.layers.concatenate`, you are passing a full model instead of just a layer. To concatenate the output layer of `ResNet` with your variable length input, you can simply replace `ResNet` by `ResNet.output` as follows:

```
ModelNet = keras.layers.concatenate([ResNet.output, VariableNet])
```